# FOR loops and variable evaluation in Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line

Consider this as the contents of a `.cmd` file:

```
@echo off
set test1=hello
echo 0 %test1%
for %%F in ( *.txt ) do (
  set test2=%%F
  echo 1 %test1%
  echo 2 %test2%
  echo 3 %%F
)
pause
```

When I run this script in Win 7 from a folder containing a.txt and b.txt as the only .txt files, I get this:

```
0 hello
1 hello
2
3 a.txt
1 hello
2
3 b.txt
Press any key to continue . . .
```

All the "successful" echo commands (starting with 0, 1 and 3) are proof that the echo and variable syntax are correct. The "unsuccessful" echo command (2) can only be the result of an unsuccessful SET command. How? Why? What SET command syntax do I need so that the `test2` variable is assigned correctly, and the output lines starting with 2 are identical to those starting with 3?

Comment: If you had done some research around, you'd see numerous related questions that are already answered. For example, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691047/batch-file-variables-initialized-in-a-for-loop).

Comment: I've now spent 3 hours of working and reading on this. Believe me - it is not the slightest bit obvious unless you already know the answer.

Comment: So you're saying that you've tried the answers there and they did not work?

Comment: No - what I was saying was that identifying what the problem is can be very hard. For example, none of the keywords I searched with showed up the answer you referred to, nor was it an answer suggested to me as I typed in the question. I found out that FOR loops had some issues around variable expansion (hence I put it in the title), but it was not clear to me if that was the issue, or the SET was the issue, or the use of the delimiters was the issue, or something else. It is very hard to search for delimiters!!

Comment: I searched "set variable in for loop batch", that was the second response.

Comment: Congratulations. I search for exactly the same words both here and in google, and that link is not on the first page of either. But by the time I had narrowed those down to being the keywords, I'd slaved for 3 hours. You spend 3 minutes and claim all the glory. Try not to sound smug (or accusative) ;-) But thanks - that link at least provided vital clues to the answer.

Comment: The answer is also buried in the middle of the SET help: `set /?` or `help set`. But I imagine most people do not bother reading it, and even if they do, it is easy to miss unless you know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SET` command is entirely fine. What is happening is that all of the `DO` block in the `FOR` command has its variables substituted when it is read the first time. At that point, the `test2` variable is empty, so that is what is echoed in the output.

To fix this, you need to use a [SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) prior to the for loop, and change the `echo %test2%` to `echo !test2!` as follows:

```
@echo off
set test1=hello
echo 0 %test1%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%F in ( *.txt ) do (
  set test2=%%F
  echo 1 %test1%
  echo 2 !test2!
  echo 3 %%F
)
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: you have your answer faster and better +1